# How to setup NextJs with tailwindcss.jit on April 2023?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, jit, setup-project

I already watch tutorials on youtube and see some website about this problem, but i did not get a same result with them... i guess because the tutorial is 2 or 1 years ago. I use `npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project` . Plis help me sir

I expect my project is already to edit and already configure with tailwind (mode : jit)